# Angular 4 : input list html of elements from the bdd (csv format)

Tags: html, angular

In my front-end (Angular), I have a form with many input fields. I want a particular field with a list of elements from a database (csv format).
So, i do a request from the server java to retrieve the list which contains all items of the database (*listOfArticles* which is an array of objects).

**Component.ts** :

```
  getListBdd() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      let subroute = "getRefNumber";
      this.managementArbo.getProducts(subroute)
        .subscribe(
          res => { this.listOfArticles = res; console.log('reponse:' + res); }

          ,
          err => console.log(err),
          () => console.log('getProducts done'));
    });
  }
```

And, in the **component.html**, i try to call the function *getListBdd()* on input and use ngFor directive on the *listOfArticles* to get all ref numbers ("*listOfArticles.refNumber.input*" returns string) :

```
<input (keyup)="getListBdd()" list="refNumbers"  formControlName="refNb" type="text" name="article[2][ref]" maxlength="15" size="15" required title="3 characters minimum"  />

          <datalist id="refNumbers" *ngFor="let ref of listOfArticles.refNumber.input">
              <option value="ref">
            </datalist>
```

In my console, i get this error "Cannot read property 'refNumber' of undefined" and i think it comes from the front (in the **component.html**), but i don't know how to fix it.

entire **component.ts** :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';


import { ManagementArbologistiqueService } from "../management-arbologistique.service";

import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-arbologistique',
  templateUrl: './arbologistique.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./arbologistique.component.css']
})
export class ArbologistiqueComponent implements OnInit {

  private reponseTest: String;
  private listOfArticles :Array<Object>
  private pathDownload: any;
  private formGroupArbologistique: FormGroup;
  fileToUpload: File = null;
  private buttonSubmitEnabled: boolean = false;

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder, private managementArbo: ManagementArbologistiqueService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroupArbologistique = this.fb.group({
      itemRows: this.fb.array([this.initItemRows()])
    })

    this.formGroupArbologistique.valueChanges.subscribe(x => this.buttonSubmitEnabled = false);
  }

  initItemRows() {
    return this.fb.group({
      ... //other fields
      refNb: ['',Validators.required],
      ... //other fields

    })
  }

  addRow(index: number) {
    console.log("functionAddRow called");
    const control = <FormArray>this.formGroupArbologistique.controls['itemRows'];
    control.insert(index, this.initItemRows());

  }

  deleteRow(index: number) {
    console.log("functionDeleteRow called");
    const control = <FormArray>this.formGroupArbologistique.controls['itemRows'];
    control.removeAt(index);
  }

  sendForm() {
    this.buttonSubmitEnabled=true;
    console.log("functionExportCalled");
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      let subroute = "exportation";
      this.managementArbo.postProducts(subroute, JSON.stringify(this.formGroupArbologistique.value))
        .subscribe(
          res => { this.reponseTest = res; console.log('reponse:' + res); }

          ,
          err => console.log(err),
          () => console.log('getProducts done'));

    });
  }

  getListBdd() {
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      let subroute = "getRefNumber";
      this.managementArbo.getProducts(subroute)
        .subscribe(
          res => { this.listOfArticles = res; console.log('reponse:' + res); }

          ,
          err => console.log(err),
          () => console.log('getProducts done'));
    });
    console.log("functionGetListBdd called " +this.listOfArticles);
  }

  get refNb() {
    return this.formGroupArbologistique.get('itemRows.refNb');
} 
}
```

entire **component.html** :

```
  <form autocomplete="off" (ngSubmit)="sendForm()" [formGroup]="formGroupArbologistique">
    <div formArrayName="itemRows">
      <table cellspacing="10" id="ajout_multi_articles">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <!-- other table headers -->
            <th>Reference Number</th>
            <!-- other table headers -->

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

          <tr class="article" *ngFor="let itemrow of formGroupArbologistique.controls.itemRows.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
            <!-- other table columns -->
            <td>
              <input (keyup)="getListBdd()" list="refNumbers"  formControlName="refNb" type="text" name="article[2][ref]" maxlength="15" size="15" required title="3 characters minimum"  />

                <datalist id="refNumbers" *ngFor="let ref of listOfArticles.refNumber.input">
                  <option value="ref">
                </datalist>
            </td>
            <!-- other table columns -->

            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btnAdd" style="background:url(assets/img/add.png)" (click)=addRow(i+1)>

              </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button type="button" class="btnDelete" style="background:url(assets/img/delete.png)" *ngIf="formGroupArbologistique.controls.itemRows.controls.length > 1" (click)=deleteRow(i)>
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>

          <button type="submit" [disabled]="!formGroupArbologistique.valid" >Valider</button>


        </tbody>


      </table>
    </div>
  </form>

  <a href="########" style="text-decoration:none;" download> 
    <button [disabled]="!formGroupArbologistique.valid || !buttonSubmitEnabled">Download</button>
  </a>
```

Sorry i did an error of syntax. Instead of write :

```
<datalist id="refNumbers" *ngFor="let ref of listOfArticles">
        <option value="ref.refNumber.input">
</datalist>
```

I wrote :

```
<datalist id="refNumbers" *ngFor="let ref of listOfArticles.refNumber.input">
       <option value="ref">
</datalist>
```

So, now, i don't have any more errors displayed in the console but i still can't display the list of ref numbers.
When i display the list with :

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor = "let ref of listOfArticles">
        ref: {{ref.refNumber.input}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

=> it works perfectly

But when i try to display the list in the datalist, no list appears. 
Maybe ngFor attribute doesn't work in a datalist ?

Comment: can you please show your component code ? ( formgroup code.. )

Comment: The template or just the component.ts ?

Comment: component.ts , otherwise both if you can

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID I edited

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution to get the list of ref numbers in a datalist :

```
<datalist id="thalesNumbers">
     <option *ngFor="let ref of listOfArticles">{{ref.refNumber.input}}</option>
</datalist>
```

Hope this can help someone !